# How to quickly find the width and height of an artwork in a layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

As per title, is there a quick way to find the width and height of an artwork in a layer?

The way I am doing now is to use `command + click` on the layer that contains the shape/artwork, and find it from the info panel. Is there a quicker and better way?

Comment: So you have already an one click method. Do you need a half-click method or something even more effective? A zero click way is to keep the transformation handles visible and see the size of the content of the current layer. It is visual only, no numbers.

Comment: There's no native shortcut for the `Select Pixels` method, which you are doing with `Cmd+Click`, but you can still do that by either making an Action or record a script using the Scripting Listener Plugin. Scripts can have more versatile shortcuts. That could make it better. That said, if I only need the dimensions/distances in pixels, I use [PixelSnap 2 for Mac](https://getpixelsnap.com/). It's often more than enough for me. You just gotta make sure to be on 100% zoom when using it. You might find these useful too: [ColorSnapper](https://colorsnapper.com/), [Sip](https://sipapp.io/)

Comment: Thanks @user287001 the method I described is acceptable in scenario where there is only 1 artwork in a layer. In cases where there are more than one artwork in a single layer the method is not efficient.

Comment: @Joonas Thanks.  I was hoping if there is any setting that just allow a hover or click on the artwork and it will show the width and height.

Comment: Jalene, PixelSnap 2 is amazing. You should totally check it out. The video on their website is pretty informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For raster layers you can use the Properties panel: layer dimensions and position are displayed on it:

[image]

For Shape layers I think <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> is the fastest way.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyKritskly